# How to create a page for authors? like www.myblog.com/author/

Tags: urls, author

I have **author.php** and it's working fine for authors separately.

**eg:**

- if I click **author1** and it goes to  `www.myblog.com/author/author1`
  and shows his details
- if I click **author2** and it goes to  `www.myblog.com/author/author2`
  and shows his details

Now I want to show all these users under 1 url like `www.myblog.com/author/author` If somone goes to `www.myblog.com/author/author/`then it should show the authors list with their details.

How can I do that.?
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit like a team/contributors page.

You could look at the [contributors page template included in the Twenty Fourteen default theme](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.8/src/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/page-templates/contributors.php) for WordPress as an excellent example. May be a challenge to use it with another theme depending on your skill level.

Another option which i have coded myself for Genesis, is a widgetized page template. This way you can use any type of author/profile widget in the widget areas. No author details are hard coded so you simply add a new widget each time you use a new author.

You could also code a page template with widgets which works with any theme.